# Cannot see Google Maps in signed application

Tags: android, google-maps, apk, code-signing

I make use of Google Maps Android V2 in my application. When I run my app without signing things are perfect but when I sign my app I cannot see maps. I get lattitude and longitude but I cannot see my maps. All I could see is some blank white space. Please Help. I need to release the project soon..

EDIT

thanks guys i missed the part where I should sign with the app keystore i tried some commands but they didnt work. Tried these

```
1. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias compny -keystore
 "C:\Users\PC8\Desktop\Sign Key" -storepass compny -keypass compny
```

and got this error

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file exists, but is empty: C:\Users
  \PC8\Desktop\Sign Key

```
2. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
 -keystore "C:\Users\PC8\Desktop\Sign Key"  -list -v
```

and got this error

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file exists, but is empty: C:\Users
\PC8\Desktop\Sign Key
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file exists, but is empty: C:\Users\PC8\De
sktop\Sign Key
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:559)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:172)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:166)

Comment: You need to sign it with the Api key during signing for google maps

Comment: Do you know how to do that..?? am sorry but am new with this signing an app..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This problem is because of map api key.
```

You need to sign your app and find .keystore for signed app. Right click on project Android Tools->Export Signed application pachage->next -> create new keystore then use this new keysore to find new SHA1 Now find new API key for your app. And replace the old map API key with this in manifest.

https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#installedapplications

Next time whenever you want new signed app just use this keystore no need to create new again.

Comment: means you generated new api key with new keystore ? If so check again all steps and make sure that you are doing in right way.There is nothing else.

Comment: got it thanks.. There was a extra character when i copied the command

Answer (score 1):

You are now probably trying to work with debug api-key which generated with debug.keystore file. You will have a private keystore file after signing your app. With this keystore file, you should get api-key which is private and named release api-key. Add this api-key to your projects `meta-data` then it will work.